# Highlighting Gtk Entry fields on invalid input by user

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3

I am creating a program using Python and Gtk. I want to guide the user by pointing out mistakes if any. I have attached a sample glade interface below. Here the user is supposed to enter a valid station name in the GtkEntry field. I want to highlight this field with red color (for instance) if he presses the submit button.

[image]

How do I achieve this in GTK3 with Python?

Comment: For a solution which does not use deprecated metods, please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065408/best-way-to-set-entry-background-color-in-python-gtk3-and-set-back-to-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you will need the `Color` class from `Gdk` and the `Gtk` class:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.Gdk import Color
```

Then, in your handler, change the foreground color of the text field:

```
COLOR_INVALID = Color(50000, 0, 0) // A dark red color
text_field.modify_fg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, COLOR_INVALID)
```

If you want to change the color back to the default when the text field is modified, put this in the change handler:

```
text_field.modify_fg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, None)
```

The RBG values for the `Color` class are in a range from 0-65535.

For more information, see the [PyGTK documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable), specifically the [Widget](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html) and [Color](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkcolor.html) classes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask if you know of a documentation source where I can find more such functions. Also this changes the color of the text. But is there a way to change the background as well?

Comment: @Nik see my updated answer. I don't know how to change the background, you could try searching the documentation.

Comment: I can't try it myself since I just reinstalled Ubuntu and don't have the dev tools yet, but maybe you could try `modify_bg` instead of `modify_fg`.

Comment: modify_fg and modify_bg are depecated in gtk3. So actually your proposal is not a good solution. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065408/best-way-to-set-entry-background-color-in-python-gtk3-and-set-back-to-default for a solution which will as well work in gtk4